# Google tag manager and angular material buttons

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have a strange issue.
I have created a tag and trigger in Google Tag Manager like this:

[image]

If I click the button on the edge, it fires the correct event, but if I click in the middle it doesn't.
Here is an image to illustrate:

[image]

If I click in the "padding" areas, everything works as expected.

But, if I click the bit in blue, it doesn't.
If I look at the debugger, I can see a click event was triggered, but no tags are fired and if I inpsect the variables I see it's caught the click of the inner span:

[image]

Is there a way I can force this to work? I thought using the CSS selector `button[data-category]` would be sufficient.

Comment: ps, it still doesn't work even if I use classes instead of the data attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an annoying issue to fix. In the end, the way I did it was by using the **DataLayer** and variables.
I basically created a service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

declare global {
  interface Window {
    dataLayer: any[];
  }
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class TagManagerService {
  constructor() {
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  }

  public engage(action: string, label: string, value: string) {
    window.dataLayer.push({
      event: 'engage',
      category: 'engage',
      action,
      label,
      value,
    });
  }
}
```

And then any time I clicked a button; in the **Click** method I would do something like this:

```
this.tagManager.engage('video play', 'Sizzle video', 'play');
```

That just meant setting up a custom event in Tag Manager like this:

[image]

Then I created a tag (Button Click)

[image]

And just for completeness, this is what my user defined variables look like:

[image]

And now, when I click a `button` the custom event fires and is recorded correctly:

[image]